# Creating a diverging color palette with a "midrange" instead of a "midpoint"

Tags: python-2.7, seaborn, color-palette

I am using python seaborn package to generate a diverging color palette (seaborn.diverging_palette).

I can choose my two extremity colors, and define if the center is light-> white or dark->black (`center`parameter). But what I would like is to extend this center part color (white in my case) to a given range of values.

For example, my values are from 0 to 20. So, my midpoint is 10. Hence, only 10 is in white, and then it becomes more green/more blue when going to 0/20. I would like to keep the color white from 7 to 13 (3 before/after the midpont), and then start to move to green/blue.

I found the `sep` parameter, which extends or reduces this center white part. But I can't find any explanation on what its value means, in order to find which value of `sep`would correspond to 3 each side of the midpoint for example.

Does anybody know the relationship between sep and the value scale ?
Or if another parameter could do the expected behaviour ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems the `sep` parameter can take any integer between `1` and `254`. The fraction of the colourmap that will be covered by the midpoint colour will be equal to `sep/256`.

Perhaps an easy way to visualise this is to use the `seaborn.palplot`, with `n=256` to split the palette up into 256 colours.

Here is a palette with `sep = 1`:

```
sns.palplot(sns.diverging_palette(0, 255, sep=1, n=256))
```

[image]

And here is a palette with `sep = 8`

```
sns.palplot(sns.diverging_palette(0, 255, sep=8, n=256))
```

[image]

Here is `sep = 64` (i.e. one quarter of the palette is the midpoint colour)

```
sns.palplot(sns.diverging_palette(0, 255, sep=64, n=256))
```

[image]

Here is `sep = 128` (i.e. one half is the midpoint colour)

```
sns.palplot(sns.diverging_palette(0, 255, sep=128, n=256))
```

[image]

And here is `sep = 254` (i.e. all but the colours on the very edge of the palette are the midpoint colour)

```
sns.palplot(sns.diverging_palette(0, 255, sep=254, n=256))
```

[image]

### Your specific palette

So, for your case where you have a range of `0 - 20`, but a midpoint range of `7 - 13`, you would want the fraction of the palette to be the midpoint to be `6/20`. To convert that to `sep`, we need to multiply by 256, so we get `sep = 256 * 6 / 20 = 76.8`. However, `sep` must be an integer, so lets use `77`.

Here is a script to make a diverging palette, and plot a colorbar to show that using `sep = 77` leaves the correct midpoint colour between 7 and 13:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

# Create your palette
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(0, 255, sep=77, as_cmap=True)

# Some data with a range of 0 to 20
x = np.linspace(0, 20, 20).reshape(4, 5)

# Plot a heatmap (I turned off the cbar here,
# so I can create it later with ticks spaced every integer)
ax = sns.heatmap(x, cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=20, cbar=False)

# Grab the heatmap from the axes
hmap = ax.collections[0]

# make a colorbar with ticks spaced every integer
cbar = plt.gcf().colorbar(hmap)
cbar.set_ticks(range(21))

plt.show()
```

[image]